# I don't understand why this code doesn't work :(

Tags: python

I am trying to not accept the username if it is not between 3 and 9 characters.

```
print (""+winner+", please input your first name, maximum of 10 characters.")
winnername = str(input())
length = (int(len(winnername)))
if 3 > length > 10:
    loop5 = 1
    while loop5 == 1:
        print ("name is too short")
        winnername = input()
        length = len(winnername)
        if (length) <3 and (length) <10:
            break

print ("name accept")
```

I would expect it to loop and ask the user for another input if the provided input doesn't meet the requirements outlined in the above text.

Comment: For what value of `length` will `3 > length` *and* `length > 10` ever be true?

Comment: For what value could `3 > length > 10` possibly be true?! `length < 3 and length < 10` (parentheses are redundant there) can be simplified to `length < 10`, but at least it *could* be true.

Comment: BTW, `length = (int(len(winnername)))` is overly complicated. `len` already returns a number so you can drop the call to `int` and that will give you: `length = (len(winnername))`. Of course the outer parens are superfluous and the final result is `length = len(winnername)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if 3 > length > 10:` is checking to make sure that length is LESS than 3 and Greater than 10, which is impossible.

Therefore the check should be `if 2 < length < 10:` (this will be true for lengths 3 to 9)

Comment: Additionally, the `if (length) <3 and (length) <10`: will check for true if length is only smaller than 3. Replace the smaller than 3 to be bigger than 3.

Answer (score 1):

Let me fix your code, elegant and clean:

```
while True:
    # I don't know if `winner` is defined
    firstname = input(""+winner+", please input your first name, maximum of 10 characters.")
    if 3 < len(firstname) < 10:
       break
    print("name is too short or too long")

print('name accepted')
```

The problem is `3 > length > 10` will never be executed because `3` will never be greater `>` than `10`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first sentence, as far as I can see form the code you are actually trying to allow maximum number of characters to be 10, not 9.

Below is a possible solution for what you're trying to achieve. The below script will keep asking user until name length is within allowed range.

```
print ("'+winner+', please input your first name, maximum of 10 characters.")

while True:
    winnername = str(input())
    if(len(winnername) < 3):
        print("Name is too short")
    elif(len(winnername) > 10):
        print("Name is too long")
    else:
        break

print ("Name accepted")
```

You may also consider to perform some validation of *winnername* first (do not allow spaces or any other special characters).

Comment: in `winnername = str(input())` you don't need the call to `str`. As you can see in the documentation [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) already returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
winner = "Mustermann"
# Build a string called "prompt"
prompt = winner + ", please input your first name, between 3 and and 10 characters."
loopLimit = 5 # Make this a variable, so it's easy to change later
loop = 0 # Start at zero
winnername = "" # Set it less than three to start, so the while loop will pick it up
# Put the while loop here, and use it as the length check
# Use an or to explicitely join them
while True: # Set an infinite loop 
    loop += 1 # Increment the loop here. 
    # Add the string to the input command. The "input" will use the prompt
    # You don't need the "str()", since input is always a string
    winnername = input(prompt)
    length = len(winnername)
    # Separate the checks, to give a better error message
    if (length < 3): 
        print ("Name is too short!") # Loop will continue
    elif (length > 10): 
        print("Name is too long!") # Loop will continue
    else: # This means name is OK. So finish
        print("Name accepted!")
        break # Will end the loop, and the script, since no code follows the loop

    if loop >= loopLimit:
        # Raise an error to kill the script
        raise RuntimeError("You have reached the allowed number of tries for entering you name!")
```